# Lotus Notes: the linked document cannot be found in view

Tags: view, lotus-notes

There is a database from which you can attach extern files in another db - called Attachments.

Users can attach docs, but when they try to open them it occurs an error like:

```
the linked document (UNID ............. )  cannot be found in view ( UNID ............. )
```

I've looked at the ACL of both database, but i don't know what the problem may be.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Code please... This question is to generic to answer it in general.

Comment: Thanks for response. There is a library written for the attachments. What code do you want?

Comment: "Users can attach docs": HOW do they do this... Most Probably THERE is the error (I just can guess, as you do not provide any of the needed information)

Comment: Well, there is a library written for the attachments. Giving all the code is not a solution, I'll try then to debug the code, but the files are attached OK. Even though,  when some users ( not all ) try to open them, it gives that error.

Comment: You need to explain yourself a little better. You seem to be describing two databases, and I guess there's a library -- but where is that library? How is it being called? What code in the library is being called? What happens when it runs? Does any other code run at the time "when they try to open them"? For that matter, what does "when they try to open them" really mean? (I.e., which database is the user in, and what exactly does the user do?) You're going to need to be very precise here, because we can imagine lots of ways you might be doing this, and we're wrong about most of them!

Answer (score 1):

You might have to set a default view in the database. Go to the view properties in the designer client. On the tab with the I click the top option: default when database is first opened.

Comment: tvdpol: on both databases?

Comment: On the database that the links are refering to. But it does not hurt to set a default view for both db's.